# Angular main component initialized 2 times

Tags: angular

This is my bootstrap:

```
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

This is my AppComponent:

```
    <div class="container">
      // some HTML
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: AppComponent},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: ''},
];
```

But i see 'some HTML' 2 times.
How can i fix it?

Comment: Do not use AppComponent as a route component since it's declared as the bootstrap component. Basically, you're appending AppComponent to AppComponent's router-outlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending `AppComponent`'s template to the `AppComponent` that was bootstrapped. So it is interpreted by angular like this:

```
<div class="container">
  // some HTML
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<!-- Appended by router module -->
<div class="container">
  // some HTML
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

You should use in your path component the component that `AppComponent` **should load**.

Example : [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urnrqs)